# query optimisation in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

How to select object by id, then get email from that object and filter all objects by this email sqlalchemy

```
    obj = db.session.query(SomeModel).filter_by(id=some_id).first()
    email = obj.email
    db.session.query(SomeModel).filter_by(email=email)
```

How to do that in one query in SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work (untested).  You create a subquery that filters on `id` and the main query can be filtered on the subquery result.

```py
subquery = session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.id == some_id).subquery()
query = session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.email == subquery.c.email)
```